# Javascript loop to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm executing the following code every 5 seconds, but the content appears as a block all at once, ideally it should be writing to the DOM each time it loops? So each value in the array should have its own div?

```
function newfunction() {
    var obj;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

            for (var i = 0, n = obj.length; i < n; i++) {
                var divTag = document.createElement("div");
                divTag.id = "div" + i;
                divTag.innerHTML = obj[i];
                divTag.className+="nodeclass";
                document.getElementById("content").appendChild(divTag);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","verify.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.onload=function() {
    newfunction();
    setInterval("newfunction()",5000);
}
```

So on page load it gets some content, then it should be adding more every 5 secs.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running it every 5 seconds? The bug is probably in your timer (setTimeout?) code.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have each loop iteration visibly modify the DOM? Doing it in bulk is significantly less taxing on the client. If you _really_ need it separate then you can use a timeout loop construct.

Comment: setInterval("newfunction()",1000);
the loop is part of a function which is an Ajax call, surely that loop should be updating the DOM with each line though?

Comment: @bobster Can you post a small, self-contained example program that demonstrates the problem? I would like to see the rest of your code since the problem is not in this for loop. You can edit your question and put it there.

Comment: @bobster when you update the DOM via JavaScript, modern browsers generally will not show you every individual update separately. Instead, they'll repaint only when necessary, or when your code is completely finished.

Comment: Could I add a delay between each line then? Surely that would force the browser to add them seperately?

Comment: @bobster well you'd have to queue up the additions via another timer or something - there's no `sleep()` in browser JavaScript.

Comment: @bobster Please don't add a delay in between to force a browser refresh, it is expensive to redraw the DOM so the browser tries to keep it down to a minimum. You are trying to forcibly tax the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing any setTimeout or setInterval, but I would do something like this:

```
function processIt(obj, i) {
    var n = obj.length;
    if (i < n) {
        var divTag = document.createElement("div");
        divTag.id = "div" + i;
        divTag.innerHTML = obj[i];
        divTag.className+="nodeclass";
        document.getElementById("content").appendChild(divTag);
        setTimeout(function () {
            processIt(obj, ++i);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); // Or whatever "obj" is

processIt(obj, 0);
```

Comment: the setinterval isn't in the loop, but loads the loop every 5 secs.

Comment: "but the content appears as a block all at once" - that's because the browser does it so fast that something small like adding elements can't be distinguished in the milliseconds it takes to do so

Comment: You can make the setTimeout interval value smaller, but this would delay the adding of each element to the page, and make it look like there is some time in between adding each. Maybe make it 500. If you used jQuery, you could have them fade in and look more dramatic.

Comment: So in order to get them to the page seperately, I need an interval inside the loop?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Like I said, a small loop, doing a small operation, will happen very quickly, where the human eye can't actually see it. Technically, they are definitely happening separately, but it's in the span of milliseconds, so we could never see it. Even in the thousands, you really wouldn't see them being added separately very well.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the speed of the human eye. The browser doesn't redraw the screen until all the javascript code is run, a timeout gets around this by queuing up another action for another redraw cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer as you just updated your snippet.. What does your JSON-object from verify.php look like? Is it an object or an array or simple strings?

```
function retrieveContent() {
    var arrayOfElements,
        xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            arrayOfElements = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            insertElements(arrayOfElements);

            setTimeout(retrieveContent, 5 * 1000);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","verify.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function insertElements(arrayOfElements) {
  var divTag,
      i,
      n;

  for (i = 0, n = arrayOfElements.length; i < n; i++) {
    divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.id = "div" + i;
    divTag.innerHTML = obj[i];
    divTag.className+="nodeclass";
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(divTag);
  }
}

window.onload=retrieveContent;
```

[jsbin snippet](http://jsbin.com/ohipef/2/edit)

Comment: your script is loading "foo" and "bar" at the same time. How do you load them seperately?

Comment: my updated snippet does pretty much same as yours, with some minor refactoring.. would really help if you could supply some example data you expect from the server via verify.php